# Are promises lazily evaluated?

Tags: javascript, promise, lazy-evaluation, service-worker

Is the code below guaranteed to output `HERE`?

```
var p = new Promise(() => console.log("HERE"))
```

(That is, does `var p = new Promise(fn)` always execute `fn` if `p.then(…)` is never called to do something with the result?)

More specifically, in the context of service workers, if I call [`Cache.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete) but never call `.then()` on the return value (or I throw away the return value), is the cache entry guaranteed to be deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed.  The [specification of `Promise`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects) has this step which will always be evaluated:

> 9. Let completion be Call(executor, undefined, «resolvingFunctions.[[Resolve]], resolvingFunctions.[[Reject]]»).

where `executor` is what you passed to the `Promise` constructor, and [Call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-call) results in that code being run.  This all happens before the `Promise` is even returned to your `p` variable.

Comment: Or simply put: The executor function `() => console.log("HERE")` passed to the `Promise` constructor is always executed immediately.

Comment: @LUH3417 Yes, but the OP wanted to know if it was guaranteed, hence the quotes from and references to the spec showing where and how it is called, and therefore _why_ it's guaranteed.

Comment: No offense, just for users who are not familiar with "spec speech"

Answer (score 2):

As James said, it is guaranteed that the function will be called. Though this doesn't guarantee that the cache entry gets deleted!

You have to check the value of the promise resolution (`true` if the cache entry is deleted, `false` otherwise).

Comment: Ah good point, that's … unfortunate! I guess I can live with the cache entry not always being deleted, although I'm not sure how to deal with the possibility that it might happen frequently.